# Cannot mount sda1: "The device '/dev/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS."

Tags: linux, mount, dual-boot, ntfs

I've installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. When i try to mount /mnt/sda1 which is Windows part on it, i take error such that; "The device '/dev/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS."

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Invalid argument

The device '/dev/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.

Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

It is the result when i command fdisk -l;

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298,1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x29af3b15
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048 546911727 546909680 260,8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       546912254 625141759  78229506  37,3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5  *    546912256 625141759  78229504  37,3G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Close voter(s): This problem did not ‘‘go away on its own’’. It went away when the OP used [GAD3R’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/476852/80216#476864).

Comment: Answer was here first. But now it’s like i talked with myself. It was for GAD3R’s comment(answer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the exact information about the bootable windows partition before executing  `ntfsfix`:

```
sudo file -s /dev/sda1
```

Then use `ntfsfix` to fix this problem:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1
```

Finally mount your partition.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to recommend "run this utility that messes with your filesystem" without first verifying that it's actually the right partition and that it's actually NTFS that's supposed to be on there... What if it actually was a FAT filesystem (common for EFI, especially as the first partition), or ext4? It could easily leave people with an unbootable system or data loss.

Comment: I still get an error after running `sudo ntfsfix /dev/nvme0n1p3` (it's nvme; my windows is on `p3`):
`Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
No change made`

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure a valid NT file system is on /dev/sda1? Does it boot?

What you see in `fdisk`'s output is the "partition ID" and "type", given when the disk is partitioned, no file system made yet. Only after an `mkfs` (or "format" in windows speak) a file system is available and recognized.

Comment: I forgot to say, yes i can't boot windows after installing Ubuntu. After installing i could mount sda1 but now i cant. I did try Syslinux to fix Windows boot. Is there possibility to Syslinux made this partition unmountable ?

Comment: After using ntfsfix, the problem fixed. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Does 'blkid' / `lsblk`'s FSTYPE / --fs just read the partition type too, or does it check the actual filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error once, when I tried to mount a partition that I "thought" was ntfs.  Attached to a CentOS host, my `/etc/fstab` entry worked with the type specified as `ntfs`.

After moving the drive to an Ubuntu host, it would not mount.

on the Ubuntu host, `fdisk -l` reported the partition as: `HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`

After changing the `/etc/fstab` entry on Ubuntu from `ntfs` to `exfat`, all worked fine.

Go figure...