# NTFS Signature Missing

Tags: linux, mount, windows, ntfs, bootable

I've been trying to access my Windows partition using Linux bootable USB flash drive.

Looking at the size of `lsblk` output, I believe the main partition is `/dev/sda2`

```
root@linux:~# lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   2.8G  1 loop /usr/lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    0 297.6G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   1  14.4G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  14.4G  0 part /usr/lib/live/mount/medium
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
root@linux:~#
```

Unfortunately when I tried to mount it, I'm getting the following error.

```
root@linux:~# mount /dev/sda2 /tmp/test/ -t ntfs
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I've been searching around and found posts like https://askubuntu.com/questions/548417/cant-mount-ntfs-drive-ntfs-signature-is-missing but it didn't really help. I tried all the suggestions, but none of them actually work.

I also found other posts [Cannot mount sda1: "The device '/dev/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS."](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476852/cannot-mount-sda1-the-device-dev-sda1-doesnt-seem-to-have-a-valid-ntfs) but this also didn't help much

```
root@linux:~# ntfsfix /dev/sda2
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

Comment: @elbarna, please READ the question above. It's not related at all!!!

Comment: Have you tried another Gnu/Linux, people around here are fed-up with newbies installing kali and then having problems because they don't have any experience, and kali being hard to use. If you are a beginner, then chose a different Gnu/Linux, such as Debian. Else if you are an expert, and you thing kali has nothing to do with the problem, then remove tag. If you thing this is a real kali question then keep the tag, but explain why.

Comment: I've been using Linux/Unix/Solaris/HP-UX many years ... The reason I'm using Kali is because it has all the tools that I needed. Weird never heard anyone don't like Kali ... nevermind I'll edit my question. I'll remove `Kali` and replaced it with other distro. The tools in Kali? Nah, I'll just install it for the sake of this post

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, of course ... I've been using Linux & Unix many years ... different kind of distros. I've edited the questions since you guys don't like Kali.

And please read the question .. it has nothing to do with Kali

Comment: What is the output of `file -s /dev/sda2` ?